# Select statement in Promela much slower than the equivalent if statement?

Tags: spin, model-checking, promela

So I used the following line in my Promela code.

```
select( cycles: 26..31 );
```

However, it was causing state explosion. I replaced it with the following `if` statement and suddenly the state explosion problem vanished. Isn't the `select` statement I showed above supposed to be the equivalent of the `if` statement below? What is going on here?

```
if 
:: cycles = 26;
:: cycles = 27;
:: cycles = 28;
:: cycles = 29;
:: cycles = 30;
:: cycles = 31;
fi;
```

Comment: Why you tagged it with C ?

Comment: Cuz Promela generates code in C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your select statement is converted by Spin into

```
cycles = 26;
do
  :: cycles < 31 -> cycles++
  :: break
od
```

This means that there are, in every loop execution, two possibilities to choose among, i.e. two different successor states in the transition system. If not `break` is chosen, you have to do a comparison and an assignment (two states), and then continue. If you want to reach the value 31, you have had 5 comparisons and 5 assignments before, whereas in the if version there is just a non-deterministic choice for an assignment.

I visualized the two different versions with spinspider, which should make the problem better understandable.

The following picture depicts the state space generated from a program with the "if"-version, where there are clearly only 6 possibilities to choose among:

```
int cycles;

active proctype testWithIf() {
  if 
    :: cycles = 26;
    :: cycles = 27;
    :: cycles = 28;
    :: cycles = 29;
    :: cycles = 30;
    :: cycles = 31;
  fi;

  assert(cycles >= 26 && cycles <= 31);
}
```

[image: State space from if-version]

Compare to this the image generated from a program obtained as a transformation of your select statement into a do-loop:

```
int cycles;
active proctype test1() {
  cycles = 26;
  do
    :: cycles < 31 -> cycles++
    :: break
  od;

  assert(cycles >= 26 && cycles <= 31);
}
```

[image: State space from do/select version]

Do you see the differences? As I said, I think the main problem is that whereas in the if-version you just choose an assignment, you have to do multiple things in the do-version at each state where you do not choose break: You have to do the comparison, increment the counter, and then continue. This clearly generates a larger state space.